# Wordpress meta_query to compare 3 meta value with same meta key

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I would like to fetch all post that have meta_value Book, Study, Art. But when I put 3 array on meta_query system doesn't return anything, but if I put online 2 array It's work

```
// this working
     $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'content',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'media_type',
            'value' => 'Book',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'media_type',
            'value' => 'Study',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )       
    )
);


//this now working
 $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'content',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'media_type',
            'value' => 'Book',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'media_type',
            'value' => 'Study',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'media_type',
            'value' => 'Art',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are searching for the exact meta values, so did you try:

```
$args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => 10,
     'post_type'      => 'content',
     'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'media_type',
                'value'   => array( 'Art', 'Book','Study' ),
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
      ),
);
```

as your query arguments?

*Sidenote*: The parameter `numberposts` works, but `posts_per_page` is now more commonly used in `WP_Query()`.

Comment: this solution return null Array()

Comment: Strange, I guess something else is causing the problem. Any extra  `pre_get_posts` filters? Can you share the relevant SQL query?  You can get it from: `$q = WP_Query( $args );  echo $q->request;`

Comment: Yeh I don't now why don't working.. so my relevant SQL query->>

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpnew_posts.ID FROM wpnew_posts INNER JOIN wpnew_postmeta ON (wpnew_posts.ID = wpnew_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wpnew_posts.post_type = 'content' AND (wpnew_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wpnew_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wpnew_postmeta.meta_key = 'media_type' AND CAST(wpnew_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('Art','Book','Study')) ) GROUP BY wpnew_posts.ID ORDER BY wpnew_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10

Comment: This looks normal. So this `$q = WP_Query( $args );  echo $q->found_posts;` is returning `0`? Are these custom posts published? Sorry for asking this, but is the post type really `content` (just want to be sure) ? How do you add the custom fields?

Comment: I have 775 post with content post type and 787 are published.
$q = WP_Query( $args );  echo $q->found_posts return 0

Comment: This works on my install. When I tested this code, on normal posts, I just added a custom field with the meta key `media_type` with a single string value, for example `Art`. Does it matter if you use lowercase?

Comment: Yes I'm try also with lowercase but not working. My custom field `media_type` is a checkbox field in ACF and all the checkbox options start with uppercase.

Comment: That works for me too, using ACF. Can you see the custom fields in the native custom fields metabox? Do you have any extra spaces in the custom field values? Does it work with  `'value'  => array( 'Art' ) ` and `'value'  => array( 'Art', 'Study' )` ? Any PHP errors with `WP_DEBUG` activated?